# Reopen request for question  on "what physical disk is referenced by Event 7.."

Tags: support, reopen-request

My question:

[what physical disk is referenced by Event 7, Disk error "The device, \Device\Harddisk2\DR2, has a bad block."](https://superuser.com/questions/415525/what-physical-disk-is-referenced-by-event-7-disk-error-the-device-device-har)

was closed as a duplicate of:

[How do I determine which HD is involved in the Event Viewer?](https://superuser.com/questions/357891/how-do-i-determine-which-hd-is-involved-in-the-event-viewer)

It is *not* a duplicate.

Maybe the general premise is a duplicate, but the linked question is not answered, only has 1 answer (by the closer, yesterday) regarding USB drives, is old, and my question has more technical information.

More details:

1. I do not have any USB drives attached, thus the answer in How do I determine which HD is involved in the Event Viewer? is not related.
2. The answer in the other question does NOT say how to determine what physical drive is which, especially after I gave the info in my comments (drive2 != channel 0, target 1)

Therefore, please reopen my question.

Comment: FYI editing your "why this isn't a duplicate" into the question isn't necessary - just include all that info here in your meta post, and that's sufficient.

Comment: thanks for the edits slhck, improved the readability nicely :)

Answer (score 4):

I was waiting to see if there would be any reopen votes from the community, but so far there haven't been.

The way I see it, it's definitely a duplicate, although there are more details and the answer to the original apparently wasn't satisfactory. The older question hasn't been abandoned though - the user who asked has still been around and active on the site.

One solution would be for you to promote the other question with a small bounty. This makes it more likely that it'll get a good answer, and helps get more attention for it. I suspect that the correct answer to the original question will also apply to yours. If eventually the original question gets an accepted answer and that *doesn't* apply to your case, we can consider if they need to be differentiated a bit and yours reopened.